# Exterior Window Casing in Brick Exterior

Tags: windows, trim, weather-resistant

So I was attempting to install new exterior window casing on my windows due to the existing casing/trim peeling and seemingly rotting. The exterior of the home is brick so I bought some 1 1/4" x 2" brick moulding as I thought the gap between the exterior of the house and the window would be pretty big. But they seem to be significantly larger than I thought!

There were two pieces of wood which formed the casing for the window is seems, the most exterior piece of moulding I had already pulled off in this picture

[image]

At the top of the window there is around a 2&1/2" gap from the frame and the window that revealed itself after both pieces of casing were off. The gap was filled with loose cement, I just cleaned it out hoping to fill it with insulating foam. Here you can see the gap after both pieces of wood had been pulled off

[image]

there also doesn't seem to be any flashing what so ever and no drip edge installed.

The sides are even more confusing to me though, as it seems a piece of casing was installed under the actual brick exterior. Don't really know if I should remove this or what?

Clearly a noobie here, who would greatly appreciate any insight into a next course of action.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go around it with 2-by lumber. Maybe PT 2x2 on the sides and 2x3 or 2x4 up top depending on the size of the gap.